# Getting Started with Unity Framework

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, codeplex

Could anyone recommend some good resources for getting started with the [Unity framework](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/)? I've downloaded the source from [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and got it to compile. So now I've got a set of compiled binaries, where do I go next? I understand the principles of inversion of control but don't have much knowledge of the specifics of the Unity framework.

I've downloaded the Unity documentation from Codeplex but it seems to be targeted at users that already have a good working knowledge of the framework.

What I'm really looking for is some good "getting started" type guides for Unity, or maybe some basic sample applications.

Any pointers to good articles, samples or blogs gratefully received.

**Great suggestion from RichardOD:**
[Screen cast from David Hayden](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/UnityDependencyInjectionIoCScreencast.aspx)

Comment: I guess this is not the same as http://japan.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/). That is ASP.NET MVC and uses Unity for DI. David Hayden has done a [screencast](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/UnityDependencyInjectionIoCScreencast.aspx) that might be useful to you.

Comment: +1 for the screencast. Instant rush of Unity to the head.

Answer (score 2):

An on-demand web casts you can check out.  [Introduction to dependency injection with Microsoft Enterprise Library Unity Application Block](https://www106.livemeeting.com/cc/wwe_us/view?cn=guest&id=1032382093&pw=23D44136)

Edit: Fixed link.  (Link to Event ID 1032382565 is dead).

Comment: Thanks for the answer JP, am I missing something or have both of these resources expired?