# C# - Add Unity to my Visual Studio Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection, unity-container

- Is Unity a part of .net framework or is it external?
- Where can I get it and how can I add it to my project?

any good tutorial on how to use Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is external
- get it from the unity site: http://unity.codeplex.com/
- If you're having trouble setting it up, have you tried using NuGet? It should add it to your project, update your config files, etc for you.

EDIT: I haven't watched it yet, but this screencast: http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/UnityDependencyInjectionIoCScreencast.aspx is recommended in another question: [Getting Started with Unity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232643/getting-started-with-unity-framework)

Comment: I figured installing the msi automatically adds the library, and it's accessible by visual studio, So yes I added it to my project and now I am trying to figure out how to register my classes, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's part of Microsoft's Enterprise Library, which is freely downloadable from Codeplex. Enterprise Library contains various code blocks of varying usefulness including IOC (Unity), logging, data access, caching, etc..